# force-sync a video element to one or more audio elements?

Tags: reactjs, video, media

im working on a small karaoke webapp at the moment, but im having trouble syncing the audio with the video.

i have multiple media elements:

1. Music Video with the instrumental
2. second audio track with the original main singing voice (can be added quietly to give some "guidance")
3. third audio track with special things like a womans singing in the chorus, when the rest of the track is a male rapping.

the video as well as the audio-files all have the exact same length.

right now, im using simple commands like
aud.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
but that doesnt do the trick, it still often lags behind
is there a better way somehow? like maybe to natively pair these elements to another?

heres the render part:
*Edit: this only shows main vocals and video, not the 2nd vocals*

```
<div className="karaoke-video-container">
    <video id="karaoke-video" preload="auto">
    <source src={props.karaokeVideo} type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
<audio id='karaoke-vocals' src={props.karaokeVocals} type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
```

there are multiple functions to control the video, but as one example, heres a function that is meant to stop the playback, reset everything to start and play it

```
  function restartKaraoke(){
    playerVideo.pause();
    playerVocals.pause();
    playerVideo.currentTime = 0;
    playerVocals.currentTime = 0;
    playerVideo.play();
    playerVocals.play();
  }
```

i also made sure to reset the player after all the files have for sure been loaded, but that still doesnt sync it (sometimes)

i also added a sync button to sync it mid-playback, but no chance, doesnt sync:

```
 function syncVocalsToVideo(){
    playerVocals.pause();
    playerVideo.pause();
    playerVocals.currentTime = playerVideo.currentTime;
    playerVocals.play();
    playerVideo.play();
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: **(1)** Audio is most important (all visuals must sync to it). So try sync as: `playerVideo.currentTime = playerVocals.currentTime;` . **(2)** Does it look bad if the video is always paused, but on each **timeUpdate** event for audio, you set video time to equal the audio's time? **(3)** Did you know that you can create your own MP4 bytes through using Arrays? The container (MP4) has sections to put timestamps for frames, and those frames can be either audio or video. If both a/v frames have the same **Presentation Timestamp** (aka **PTS**) then the `<video>` tag will play them synchronized.